# WooCommerce aligning pictures of products

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to align the pictures of the products so that the pictures are aligned horizontally.

For example, the third picture in the first category here is upper compared to the other 2 because its title is shorter. How can I have all the pictures aligned just like in a table?

(link for the example is [this](https://theplate.ro/meniu/))

Comment: Add a min-height with CSS for the title (h2)

Comment: That works, but it looks awkward for products without thumbnails - is there a way to do it only for certain products even if that means I need to hardcode it?

Comment: There are several answers possible, to give an appropriate answer you will have to add some more details to your question. What have you tried so far? do you have access to the template file? do you know how to override this? etc..

Comment: I eventually solved it by doing what you did, but for certain products. you can post an answer and I'll mark it as correct though

Comment: as you wish, you can also delete your question. Several similar questions can be found on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, one of which is to add a min-height with CSS for the title (h2)

```css
.type-product .woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    min-height: 63px;
}
```